# MYSQL DISTINCT keyword not working

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

i have used DISTINCT keyword for my search query , but its not working. please advice

```
   $query="SELECT b.title,b.id, b.metakey
    FROM categories b
    WHERE  b.title like '%".$searchc."%' AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND b.level=3
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT a.title,  a.id, a.title as metakey
    FROM  content a join
          categories b
          on a.categories_id = b.id
    WHERE a.title like '%".$searchc."%'AND b.parent_id BETWEEN 84 AND 107 AND b.level=3
     ";
```

im using this query for  my ajax autocomplete search, when i type a title name , if there exists more than in same title all data displaying on dropdwon , where as my requirement is to display it once time . please advice

Comment: Not working is not enough information, please provide DDL and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with your expected output.

Comment: It is working! You don't get a single duplicate **row**. You might get  dupkicate **fields** though, which is expected behaviour.

Comment: What is it actually returning, and what did you expect it to return?

Comment: And, just for the record, the `distinct` is unnecessary because `union` removes distinct *records*.  If you only want one row per value in some column, think about `group by`.

Comment: this query i have used for search module in my site. when im type title name autocomplete dropdown shows multiple values with same name. i want to avoid that and if the same title repeated on db i want to display it one time . please advice @ChrisBogart

Comment: @GordonLinoff : thanks for the hint , Group by was works !!

Comment: I dislike this use of GROUP BY. Under certain circumstances it can lead to erroneous or unexpected results, and points to a failure of design.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a.id is the unique identity of an entry?
As a result, every record of (a.title,  a.id) is unique.

```
id  title
1   A Man
2   A Son
3   A Man
...
```

U see what I mean?

Comment: I think you should probably do: "SELECT DISTINCT a.title as metakey..."

Answer (score -1):

While using the `Distinct` in `SELECT` statement with selecting many number of fields it may not works properly;

*Solution:* Use `GROUP BY` clause for distinct fields